# How to show the entire background-image in <p:commandLink>?

Tags: css, jsf, primefaces

I have a `<p:commandLink>` wherein I want to show a picture as CSS backgound image:

```css
.button{
    background-image: url(http://www.lefinnois.net/aqua/aqua1.jpg);
    background-size: 50px;    
}
```

```html
<p:commandLink update="media" value="Kaydet"
    action="#{productView.save}" styleClass="button">
</p:commandLink>
```

But I need the command link to have the same width and height as the background image. If I add the following property to the CSS

```
background-size: 50px;
```

then I can see a small portion of the image. If I don't add this, I cannot see the image.

If I try to add this to the CSS

```
width: 100px;
height: 50px;
```

then nothing changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tag `<a/>` generated by `p:commandLink` is an inline html element and as such has cannot have its size set. You can override it by setting `display` css attribute to `inline-block` - or use `p:commandButton` instead.

Comment: like this? :`.button{
   background-image: url(http://www.lefinnois.net/aqua/aqua1.jpg);
   display:inline-block;
   }`

Comment: very useful answer, thanks in advance. exactly like above comment.

Comment: @tuxi yes, and also width/height if needed.

Comment: sorry, one more question, how can i align text in image both verticaly and horizontaly, i tried `text-align:center`, it centers only horizontaly.

Comment: @tuxi there is a separate css attribute, `vertical-align`

Comment: but how can i set `vertical-align` of text in `commandLink`? in my `.button{}` class? i tried `.button p{}` and `.button text{}` could get no response.